# Differential equation for heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

> Consider the equation $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + a\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$ for a function $u(x,t)$ with initial value $$u(x,0)=f(x).$$ Let $\hat{u}(y,t)$ and $\hat{f}(y)$ denote the Fourier transform in the $x$ variable of $u$ and $f$. For each fixed $y$, find the ordinary differential equation for $\hat{u}(y,t)$ formally (assuming the derivatives all make sense). Then solve the equation for $\hat{u}$ in terms of $\hat{f}$.

Taking the Fourier transform, I get $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\hat{u}(y,t)=(iy)^2\hat{u}(y,t)+aiy\hat{u}(y,t)=-y^2\hat{u}(y,t)+aiy\hat{u}(y,t)$$

But how can I solve the equation for $\hat{u}$ in terms of $\hat{f}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\uu}{\,{\rm u}}$
$\ds{\partiald{\uu}{t} = \partiald[2]{\uu}{x} + a\partiald{\uu}{x}\,,\quad \uu\pars{x,0} = \fermi\pars{x}}$.

> $$
> \uu\pars{x,t} \equiv \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
> \tilde{\uu}\pars{k}\exp\pars{\ic kx - {t \over \tau_{k}}}\,{\dd k \over 2\pi}
> \quad\imp\quad
> -\,{1 \over \tau_{k}} = -k^{2} + \ic ka
> $$

\begin{align}
&\uu\pars{x,t} \equiv \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\tilde{\uu}\pars{k}\expo{\ic kx + \pars{-k^{2} + \ic ka}t}\,{\dd k \over 2\pi}\
\imp\
\uu\pars{x,0} = \fermi\pars{x} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\tilde{\uu}\pars{k}\expo{\ic kx}\,{\dd k \over 2\pi}\tag{1}
\end{align}

> Notice that $\tilde{\uu}\pars{k}$ is the $\fermi\pars{x}$ Fourier transform $\hat{\fermi}\pars{k}$ ( in the OP notation ):
> $\hat{\fermi}\pars{k} \equiv \tilde{\uu}\pars{k}$. In terms of it ( $\underline{\mbox{as required by the OP}}$ ) the solution is ( see expressions $\pars{1}$ ):
> $$\color{#ff0000}{\large\bf%
> \uu\pars{x,t} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
> \hat{\fermi}\pars{k}\expo{\ic kx + \pars{-k^{2} + \ic ka}t}\,{\dd k \over 2\pi}}
> \tag{2}
> $$

\begin{align}
&\tilde{\uu}\pars{k} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\fermi\pars{x}\expo{-\ic k x}\,\dd x
\quad\imp\quad
\uu\pars{x,t} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm K}\pars{x - x',t}\fermi\pars{x'}\,\dd x'
\\[3mm]&
\mbox{where}\quad
{\rm K}\pars{x,t}
\equiv
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{\ic kx - \pars{k^{2} - \ic ka}t}\,{\dd k \over 2\pi} 
\end{align}
Let's evaluate ${\rm K}\pars{x,t}$:
\begin{align}
{\rm K}\pars{x,t}
&\equiv
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{-t\bracks{k^{2} - \ic\pars{x/t + a}k}}\,{\dd k \over 2\pi}
=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\expo{-t\bracks{k - \ic\pars{x/t + a}/2}^{2} - t\pars{x/t +a}^{2}/4}
\,{\dd k \over 2\pi} 
\\[3mm]&=
\expo{-\pars{x + at}^{2}/4t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{-tk^{2}}
\,{\dd k \over 2\pi} 
\quad\imp\quad
{\rm K}\pars{x,t} = {\expo{-\pars{x + at}^{2}/4t} \over \root{2\pi}\root{2t}}
\end{align}
$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\uu\pars{x,t}
=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\fermi\pars{x'}
{\expo{-\pars{x\ -\ x'\ +\ at}^{2}/4t} \over \root{2\pi}\root{2t}}\,\dd x'}
$$

Comment: Hi Felix. Thanks for your answer, but sorry I'm really lost how this helps with my question (solving for $\hat{u}$ in terms of $\hat{f}$)

Comment: @Kunal I rewrote somehow the solution such that you can see your required solution is already here $\left(~\mbox{see the}\  \color{#ff0000}{\large\bf\mbox{RED}}\ \mbox{formula}~\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the Fourier transform in $x$ converts the $x$ derivatives to multiplication, so the only derivative left will be with respect to $t$ - hence giving an ODE.